# How to get Tax amount programatically when user is Tax Exempt in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating tax exemption rules with my plugin to exempt certain users from paying tax, by using

```
$customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);
```

Works great. However, some use cases require that tax is paid by users in cart/checkout, even though price display throughout the site should be tax-free.

So I am trying to add a fee for what the normal tax amount would be, if not tax-exempt. I am trying to do this with `"woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees"`, but how can I get the normal cart total tax amount? Every function I've tried gives me the exempted version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the opposite of clean and efficient code, but at least it works:

```
$tax_vat = 0;
$tax_name = 'VAT';
                    $cart = WC()->cart;
                    foreach($cart->get_cart() as $item){
                        //Get product by supplying variation id or product_id
                        $product = wc_get_product( $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'] );
                        if ($product->is_taxable()){
                            $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates( $product->get_tax_class() );
                            if (!empty($tax_rates)) {
                                $tax_rate = reset($tax_rates);
                                $tax_vat += (wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product) * $tax_rate['rate'] * $item['quantity'])/100;
                                $tax_name = $tax_rate['label'];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $cart->add_fee( $tax_name, $tax_vat);
```